# Parallel lines relation to

Tags: geometry

We have 2 Straight and parallel line L1 and L2, L2 is also 
paralle to third L3 straight line, how to prove L1 is paralle to L3 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The property of being parallel is transitive.
See here: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Parallelism_is_Transitive